# Closing Python Tkinter window mainloop without a button

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to refresh a python Tkinter window every 1 seconds :

```
animation=TFS(test) #animation is a list, each item in the list is a table with drawing input information.
for item in animation:
    Display(item) #display function is creating a Tkinter window with a mainloop
    time.sleep(1)
```

The only solution about closing a mainloop for Tkinter that i found on the internet, is by using .quit() or .destroy() in a button.

But I don't want the user to close the window manually, the window should be closed automatically every x second in order to be able to display a new window with updated information.

Note : the display is made of about 2 hundreds rectangles and labels.

Comment: You do not need to close the window, just update the data within it instead

Answer (score 0):

The `.destroy()` method can be called anywhere in the code, not necessarily when button is pressed. To close the window, it has to be called on `Tk` object (main window, the first one you created). But, like [@Billal BEGUERADJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5906918/billal-begueradj) said, you don't need to close the window to refresh widgets inside it. Just call `.config()` method on the widget you'd like to modify and pass options you'd like to change as arguments.

Comment: I don't succeed to call  .destroy() or .config() before the time.sleep(1)  because of the .mainloop() in the function Display.

Answer (score 0):

The display in the canva is procedural with hundreds of shapes, so the `.configure` seems hard to used.

So i deleted the `.mainloop()` in the function Display and replaced it by :

```
TK.update()
time.sleep(RefreshTime)
TK.destroy()
return
```

and changed the main code to the following :

```
animation=TFS(test)       
for step in animation:
     Display.display(step,RefreshTime)
```